# tkinter deleting a messagebox contents

Tags: tkinter, tkmessagebox

I use a messagebox as a widget to display results from a random number generator. The number of random numbers is chosen through an entry box. Using

```
def evClear():
    from_draws.delete(0,END)# clears only entry value
    from_draws.focus()
    cvt_to.delete()
```

I succesfuklly delete the contents of the entry box (from_draws), however the cvt_to which contains the random numbers gives an error:
AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'delete'
How can one delete both ( simply to make the GUI look a bit better)? If one places a different number in the entry box, the reruslt is ovwerwritten by the new result. I guess the question is how to delete the contents written to a messagebox, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
cvt_to.delete()
```

by

```
cvt_to.set("")  # set to empty string
```

Comment: Happens to everyone. That's one of the reasons this community exists :)